# Как описать модель данных в UML?

Tags: google-analytics, uml, visio

Есть заказчик, который занимается on-line продажей виски класса премиум.

В целях повышения продаж заказчик собирается заняться продажей подарочных коробок для виски.

Менеджер по продажам на стороне заказчика выбрал 5 типов подарочных коробок, которые будут представлены в интернет-магазине.

Клиент выставил функциональные требования к ПО:

На сайте интернет магазина необходимо показывать товар (виски) вместе с подходящей подарочной коробкой.
Коробки подобраны следующим образом: 
Не все подарочные коробки подходят ко всем бутылкам, но каждая бутылка виски будет иметь по крайней мере одну подходящую подарочную коробку (может быть несколько).

С помощью каких диаграмм можно описать модель данных, которая позволит решить задачи проекта?

Быть может, стоит выбрать альтернативу UML? Подскажите.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно подойдёт диаграмма классов, где ваши бутылки и коробки будут классами с атрибутами,соединенные связями один ко многим, один к одному и т.д. Нужно грамотно оформить только